# Set environment in AWS codebuild for Android build

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, aws-codebuild

I am trying install Android environment in AWS server.
Here it is buildspec.yml file that contain set of command to install
Android SDK, NDK and **gradlew** for generate android build .
SDK and NDK for Android successfully downloaded and installed at AWS Ubuntu system. Even I can see a log for **./gradlew build** that build
successfully.

**buildspec.yml**

```
version: 0.1

phases:
  install:
    commands:
      - echo Nothing to do in the install phase...
      - sudo apt-get -y install wget
  pre_build:
    commands:
      - echo Nothing to do in the pre_build phase...
      - wget http://dl.google.com/android/android-sdk_r24.4.1-linux.tgz
      - tar zxvf android-sdk_r24.4.1-linux.tgz
      - mkdir -p android-sdk-linux/licenses
      - cp android-sdk-license ./android-sdk-linux/licenses/
      - echo sdk.dir='pwd'/android-sdk-linux > local.properties
      - wget https://dl.google.com/android/repository/android-ndk-r13b-linux-x86_64.zip
      - unzip android-ndk-r13b-linux-x86_64.zip
      - export ANDROID_NDK_HOME=`pwd`/android-ndk-r13b
      - export PATH=${PATH}:${ANDROID_HOME}/tools:${ANDROID_HOME}/platform-tools:${ANDROID_NDK_HOME}
      - echo "sdk.dir=$ANDROID_HOME" > local.properties
      - echo "ndk.dir=$ANDROID_NDK_HOME" >> local.properties
  build:
    commands:
      - root/./gradlew --debug --stacktrace build
      - root/./gradlew assemble

  post_build:
    commands:
      - echo Build completed on `date`
artifacts:
   files:
    - Monoca/app/**/*
```

While I try to execute **./gradlew assemble** command for Android build it can generate application file (.apk) in Android output directory in Android Studio
but unfortunately it's not working in AWS CodeBuild environment.

Anyone have deep insight regarding this issue ? Please suggest if you find anything wrong in set up part.

[I have followed this tutorial for AWS CodeBuild.](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/codebuild/latest/userguide/getting-started.html)

Comment: What is `root/./gradlew`? Why is the `.` there?

Comment: Also `echo sdk.dir='pwd'` is using the wrong quotes

Comment: root/./gradlew it's path to execute gradlew command in sub directory otherwise it can't find .I checked that traces and it work for ./gradlew build

Comment: But `root/gradlew` is the exact same. That's my main point. Or you can go from `/path/to/the/project/gradlew`... Or even go and download and setup Gradle itself like you did for the SDK, then you can run `gradle` as if it were on the `PATH`

Comment: It means '''cd projectPath''' and run this gradlew command right ?

Comment: There is no `cd` being done. You are just giving the path to the command. But, `root/` more than likely is not a directory that can be accessed. You should give the full path exactly., but I don't know what that is.

Answer (score 6):

I think the problem here is with propagating the environment variable values across commands that CodeBuild does not follow. CodeBuild executes each commands in fresh shell. The last 2 commands would essentially set sdk.dir and ndk.dir variables to be empty (you can validate this by running `cat local.properties`).

`- echo "sdk.dir=$ANDROID_HOME" > local.properties
- echo "ndk.dir=$ANDROID_NDK_HOME" >> local.properties`

The right approach here would be to move your build logic to a script that gets executed from the buildspec.yml

`- ./my-gradle-build.sh`

or

Not use the environment variables to set variables in local.properties, but use paths instead.

`- echo sdk.dir='pwd'/android-ndk-r13b > local.properties
- echo ndk.dir='pwd'/android-ndk-r13b >> local.properties`

I hope this helps.

Thanks!